# OWIN self-host IAppBuilder map if part of Windows group

Tags: owin, windows-authentication, katana

I have following setup:

Self-host OWIN server (Windows Service). In the OWIN startup class, I configured httpListener to only allow Windows Authentication. This works.

```
...
HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)app.Properties["System.Net.HttpListener"];
listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.IntegratedWindowsAuthentication;

this.ConfigureSomeApp();
...

private void ConfigureSomeApp()
{
    app.Map("/someapp", someApp => { //appconfig here, ommitted for brevity };
}
```

The thing I'm trying to achieve is to ONLY map "someapp" based on some conditions regarding the current user (i.e. if the user is a member of a specified Windows group).

I cannot seem to find how to do this. Is this possible ? Something like:

```
private void ConfigureSomeApp()
{
    if(currentuser is in windowsgroup) //pseudo example condition I want to achieve
        app.Map("/someapp", someApp => { //appconfig here, ommitted for brevity };
}
```

If not possible here in the startup class, what are your other suggestions on how to achieve this ?

For info: I do not control the "someapp" implementation, it comes from a NuGet package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the correct way to do this

```
{
    if(currentuser is in windowsgroup) //pseudo example condition I want to achieve
        app.Map("/someapp", someApp => { //appconfig here, ommitted for brevity };
}
```

because `ConfigureSomeApp` method is in startup and startup only run once, therefor your if statement won't run for every request.

You have to use `app.MapWhen`

```
app.MapWhen(context =>
        {
            // check the logic for user
            //context.Authentication.User

            return true; // return true if you want to map for this request
        }, someapp => /*config someapp*/);
```